# Why aren't the ages when Jacob and Joseph became fathers mentioned?

Tags: genesis, mathematics, genealogy, jacob, joseph

Of all the generations in Genesis, the age at which each became a father/begot a son/twins were born is **almost** always shown. The only exceptions are the last two, Jacob and Joseph.

Why might that be the case?

<sub>**Note:** Jacob’s and Joseph’s ages for becoming fathers can be calculated, but only when considering unique data like Jacob’s “*years as a wayfarer amount to 130*” (Genesis 47:9) and “*Joseph was 30 years old when he entered the service of Pharaoh, king of Egypt*" (Genesis 41:46).</sub>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ussher provides answer half of your question in his work, [Annuls of the World](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=genesis%2026:34&version=NKJV):

> Jacob was ninety-one years old when Joseph was born, and consequently,
>   seventy-seven years old when he first began to serve Laban.  This may
>   be deduced, for Jacob was a hundred and thirty years old when he first
>   stood before Pharaoh at the time when the seven years of plenty were
>   past and two years of famine were over. {Ge 45:6 47:9} Joseph was then
>   thirty-nine years old.  He was thirty years old when he first came
>   before Pharaoh, just before the seven years of plenty {Ge 41:32, 46}.